# Finding the solution for an exponential equation algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the solution of the exponential equation, rounded to four decimal places.

$$2^{ 3x+1 }=3^{ x-2 }$$

Steps I took:

1. $log2^{ 3x+1 }=log3^{ x-2 }$
2. $3x+1log2\quad =\quad x-2log3$
3. $\frac { 3x+1 }{ x-2 } =\frac { log3 }{ log2 } $

Afterwards, I plugged both sides of the equation into my graphing calculator and took down the point at which the two lines intercepted which was $\approx -2.9545$

However, the answer key has a different approximation. How do I get the same one? I assume I'd have to solve algebraically for that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second step has to be the following : $$\begin{align}\color{red}{(}3x+1\color{red}{)}\log 2=\color{red}{(}x-2\color{red}{)}\log 3&\iff 3x\log 2+\log 2=x\log 3-2\log 3\\&\iff 3x\log 2-x\log 3=-2\log 3-\log 2\\&\iff (3\log 2-\log 3)x=-2\log 3-\log 2\\&\iff x=\frac{-2\log 3-\log 2}{3\log 2-\log 3}=\frac{\log (1/(18))}{\log (8/3)}\approx -2.9469\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your calculation, this is the correct method:
$$\ \log(2^{(3x+1)})=\log(3^{(x-2)})\iff(3x+1)\log2=(x-2)\log3$$

and now solve for $\ x$.

Another way is to apply the $\log$ later:

$$\ 2^{3x+1}=3^{x-2}\iff2\cdot2^{3x}=\frac{3^x}{3^2}\iff2\cdot8^x=\frac{3^x}{9}\iff(\frac{8}{3})^x=\frac{1}{18}$$

$$\ \log(\frac{8}{3})^x=\log(\frac{1}{18})\iff x\cdot\log(\frac{8}{3})=\log(\frac{1}{18})\iff x=\frac{\log(\frac{1}{18})}{\log(\frac{8}{3})}$$

as in the mathlove answer